# Riccati equation in optimal control problem

Tags: calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

Using Riccati equation

$$\dot{P} = - PA - A^\textrm{T}P + P B R^{-1} B^{\textrm{T}} P - Q,\ P(T)= F$$

find the optimal minimum cost $J$ if

$$\dot{x} = 2x + u,\;J(u) = 5 x^2(1) + \int_0^1 \left[x^2(t) + u^2(t)\right]dt, \;x(0) = x_0.$$

I can't see how to relate Riccati equation to this problem. Any ideas on how to start will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I general this problem can be formulated using the following dynamics

$$
\dot{x} = A\,x + B\,u,
\tag{1}
$$

with $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $u\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $(A,B)$ stabilizable. The goal is the find the control input $u(t)$ which solves

$$
\min_u \int_0^T
\begin{bmatrix}
x(t) \\ u(t)
\end{bmatrix}^\top
\begin{bmatrix}
Q & N \\
N^\top & R
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x(t) \\ u(t)
\end{bmatrix}
\,dt + x(T)^\top Q_T\,x(T),
\tag{2}
$$

with $R = R^\top \succ 0$, $Q_T = Q_T^\top\succeq0$, $Q = Q^\top$, $Q - N\,R^{-1} N^\top = W^\top W \succeq 0$ and $(A,W)$ detectable. It can be noted that in the case when $N = 0$ $(2)$ simplifies to

$$
\min_u \int_0^T
\left(x(t)^\top Q\,x(t) + 
u(t)^\top R\,u(t)\right) dt + x(T)^\top Q_T\,x(T).
\tag{3}
$$

Finding the optimal input can be solved by starting at the end and go backwards in time, similar to [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). In order to do this only the terminal cost and the last sliver of the integral from $(2)$ are taken into consideration

$$
\min_u \int_{T-\delta}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
x(t) \\ u(t)
\end{bmatrix}^\top
\begin{bmatrix}
Q & N \\
N^\top & R
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x(t) \\ u(t)
\end{bmatrix}
\,dt + x(T)^\top Q_T\,x(T).
\tag{4}
$$

By making $\delta$ in $(4)$ infinitesimally small and for convenience use $\chi = x(T-\delta)$ and $\mu = u(T-\delta)$ then the integral in the cost function can be written as one term of Riemann sum. Because $\delta$ is infinitesimally small $x(T)$ can be expressed using Euler's method $x(T) = x(T-\delta) + \delta\,\dot{x}(T-\delta)$. Applying this to $(4)$ yields

$$
\min_\mu 
\begin{bmatrix}
\chi \\ \mu
\end{bmatrix}^\top
\begin{bmatrix}
Q & N \\
N^\top & R
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\chi \\ \mu
\end{bmatrix}
\,\delta + \left(\chi + \delta(A\,\chi + B\,\mu)\right)^\top Q_T\,\left(\chi + \delta(A\,\chi + B\,\mu)\right).
\tag{5}
$$

When discarding all negligible $\delta^2$ terms in $(5)$ and rewriting it into one quadratic form yields

$$
\min_\mu 
\delta\,\mu^\top R\,\mu +
2\,\delta\,\mu^\top \left(N + Q_T B\right)^\top \chi + 
\chi^\top \left(Q_T + \delta\,(Q + A^\top Q_T + Q_T A)\right)\chi,
\tag{6}
$$

which can be shown to have to solution

$$
\mu = -R^{-1} \left(N + Q_T B\right)^\top \chi.
\tag{7}
$$

Substituting $(7)$ into the cost function of $(6)$ gives the minimal cost to go from $t = T - \delta$ to $t = T$ given $x(T - \delta)$

$$
\label{eq:optimal_cost_end}
\left.J_{\min}\right|_{T-\delta}^T = 
\chi^\top \left[Q_T + \delta\left(Q + A^\top Q_T + Q_T A - (N + Q_T B) R^{-1} (N + Q_T B)^\top\right)\right] \chi.
\tag{8}
$$

When considering the next infinitesimally small time step back in time the same type of problem is encountered, only the terminal cost defined with $Q_T$ is replaced with $(8)$. The matrix $P(t)$ is defined as the equivalent $Q_T$ at time $t$, thus $P(T) = Q_T$. The term added to $Q_T$ in $(8)$ is proportional to $\delta$, so the update of $P(t)$, interpreting it as Euler's method, can also be written as the following matrix differential equation

$$
-\dot{P} = Q + A^\top P + P\,A - \left(N + P\,B\right) R^{-1} \left(N + P\,B\right)^\top,
\tag{9}
$$

which is a Riccati differential equation. It can be noted that the minus sign in front of $\dot{P}$ is there because it starts at $P(T)=Q_T$ and then goes backwards in time. Using $P(t)$, $x(t)$ and $u(t)$ instead of $Q_T$, $\chi$ and $\mu$ respectively the optimal control solution shown in $(7)$ can be generalized to

$$
u(t) = -R^{-1} \left(N + P(t)\,B\right)^\top x(t).
$$

It can be noted that $x(\tau)^\top P(\tau)\,x(\tau)$ is equal to the minimal cost from $t=\tau$ to $t=T$ given $x(\tau)$. For the infinite horizon problem $T = \infty$ the final state $x$ and thus also the input $u$ can be assumed to go to zero, so $Q_T$ would be meaningless. Instead it can be assumed that $P$ converges to a constant value, which for any finite amount of time will remain constant. This constant value for $P$ can be obtained by setting $(9)$ to zero

$$
Q + A^\top P + P\,A - \left(N + P\,B\right) R^{-1} \left(N + P\,B\right)^\top = 0,
\tag{10}
$$

which is also known as a continuous algebraic Riccati equation (CARE).